# post値へのページアクセス

Tags: php, smarty

現在、smartyを使っています。
その中で、トップページから特定のページにアクセスするようにしたいのですが
そのアクセス先がpost値で制御されている場所になります。
tplのlocationにアドレスを指定しても上手くいかないのはわかるのですが、
例えばpost値がxxx=1とxxx=2で表示内容が変わるページの場合はどこに何を指定してあげれば
xxx=1やxxx=2のページにアクセスできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

POSTデータの条件で特定のページがアクセスの制御がかかっている場合は、POSTデータを特定のページに渡す必要があります。

POSTデータを渡す方法は入力フォームでデータを送信する必要があります。
以下を参考にフォームによる画面遷移をしてください。
フォームデータを送信する
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data